# Easyrtc data exchange through websockets

Tags: websocket, socket.io, easyrtc

Think I must be missing something, but I don't have the debug capability to check. Web app passes data to node.js server through socket.io, but doesn't emit anything back.

server.js

```
// Load required modules
var http    = require("http");              // http server core module
var express = require("express");           // web framework external module
var io      = require("socket.io");         // web socket external module
var easyrtc = require("easyrtc");           // EasyRTC external module

// Setup and configure Express http server. Expect a subfolder called      "static" to be the web root.
var httpApp = express();
httpApp.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static/"));

// Start Express http server on port 8080
var webServer = http.createServer(httpApp).listen(8080);

// Start Socket.io so it attaches itself to Express server
var socketServer = io.listen(webServer, {"log level":1});

 // Start EasyRTC server
 var rtc = easyrtc.listen(httpApp, socketServer);

easyrtc.events.on('get_candy', function(easyrtc) {
  easyrtc.events.emit('did it');
});
```

file.js

```
function joined_room() {
easyrtc.sendServerMessage('get_candy', {candy_name:'mars'},
        function(msgType, msgData ) {
           console.log("got candy count of " + msgData.barCount);
        },
        function(errorCode, errorText) {
           console.log("error was " + errorText);
        });
}

easyrtc.setServerListener( function(msgType, msgData, targeting) {
    console.log("The Server sent the following message " + JSON.stringify(msgData));
}, 'get_candy');
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem few months ago and now my solution is reuse websocket on server:
In client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
easyrtc.useThisSocketConnection(socket);
```

In server side:

```
var io      = require("socket.io");         // web socket external module
var easyrtc = require("easyrtc");           // EasyRTC external module

var httpApp = express();
httpApp.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static/"));

// Start Express http server on port 8080
var webServer = http.createServer(httpApp).listen(8080);

// Start Socket.io so it attaches itself to Express server
var socketServer = io.listen(webServer);

var rtc = easyrtc.listen(webServer, io, null, function(err, rtcRef) {
  rtcRef.events.on('roomCreate', function(appObj, creatorConnectionObj, roomName, roomOptions, callback) {
    console.log('roomCreate fired!');
  });
});
```

This snip allows you reuse your websocket for easyRTC. Signature message for RTC and other can using same websocket.